# Is NSString copied when passed in as a parameter of a block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

In order to make my code dry, I am writing the following code.

```
void (^setItemAndClearCounterpart)(id, id, id) = ^(id item, id counterpart, id text){

    if ([text length] > 0 && ![text isEqualToString:@"default"]) {
        counterpart = @"default";  // Here we change the "counterpart" passed in
    }
    if ([text length] == 0) {
        text = @"default";
    }
    item = text;  // Here we change the "item" passed in
};

                 // These items in the array are NSString
NSArray *itemArr = @[_settings.selfPushSound,   _settings.selfBgImage,   _settings.selfBgSound,
                     _settings.commonPushSound, _settings.commonBgImage, _settings.commonBgSound];

setItemAndClearCounterpart( itemArr[ (alertView.tag + 3) % 6 ],
                            itemArr[  alertView.tag      % 6 ],
                            text);
// PROBLEM: properties of _settings (eg. _settings.selfPushSound ) not changed by the block
```

However, it seems that the NSStrings I passed in not get changed by the block as I thought they would be.

I wonder if the NSStrings are copied when they are passed in as parameters of a block? Or if they are copied when they are added to an NSArray?

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong but essentially yes. Non-local variables are copied by the block as `const` variables and are read-only. You could prefix `__block` to the variables but seeing as they're properties I'm not sure if thats good practice

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `NSString` or blocks (specifically). All parameters in Objective-C are passed by value. This is true for blocks, methods, and functions.

All method, function, and block parameters are essentially local variables. When you do:

```
item = text;
```

at the end of the block, all you are doing is changing which object the local variable `item` is pointing to. That in no way changes the value used to call the block.

The only way to get a value changed outside the block is to use an "out" parameter. This is done in Objective-C by passing a pointer to the value.

A common example of this can be found in many methods that take an `NSError **` parameter. Note that it's a pointer to a pointer to an `NSError`.

Comment: It's important to note that it's the *pointer* that is passed by value.  The NSString object itself is not copied (nor is any other object).

Comment: @HotLicks thanks for making that clear.  I should have been more specific on that point.